# ng-select Angular2 panel transparent

Tags: css, angular, colors

I have some problem with ng-select css, my dropdown panel color is transparent (normally default color is white) on Chrome and Firefox.

html

```
            <ng-select class="custom"[items]="mesurePoints2"
            bindLabel="name"
            bindValue="name"
            [ngModel]="actualMesurePoint.name"
            name="name"
             (ngModelChange)="mesurePointSelection($event)"
            >
           </ng-select>
```

css

```
  .ng-select.custom {
  border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  }
  .ng-select.custom .ng-option {
  background-color: red;
  }
```

component

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-traffic-data',
templateUrl: './traffic-data.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./traffic-data.component.scss', '../../../app.disabled.scss',
    '../../../../../node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css'],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`encapsulation`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) in order to override children component's css:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-traffic-data',
templateUrl: './traffic-data.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./traffic-data.component.scss', '../../../app.disabled.scss',
    '../../../../../node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

[Example stackbiltz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2ltmy).

Comment: in that case, please consider voting on it and marking this answer as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for your question :)

Answer (score 2):

You should just import `"./node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css"` or `"./node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme.css"` in `style.scss`:

```
@import "@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css";
```

or directly in `angular.json` like this :

```
 "styles": [
       ...,
       "./node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css",
       ...
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `encapsulation` solution did not work for me. But using adding the `appendTo="body"` attribute to the `ng-select` worked like magic for me.

You can refer to [this issue thread](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/799#issuecomment-463958710) on ng-select library for more details.